# set max_execution_time on joomla docker

Tags: php, docker, joomla

i need to increase max_execution_time on an docker running joomla. I modified my php.ini and pass it to the docker by volume:

```
cat /data/php.ini

upload_max_filesize = 101M
post_max_size = 101M
max_execution_time = 666
```

my run docker run

```
docker run -d \
    --name myjoomla \
    -p 80:80 \
    -e JOOMLA_DB_NAME=dbname \
    -e JOOMLA_DB_USER=user \
    -e JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD=pass \
    -e JOOMLA_DB_HOST=host \
    -v /data/www/html:/var/www/html \
    -v /data/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini \
    --restart=always \
    joomla:latest
```

for the other variables it works but not for max_execution_time

```
$ docker exec -it myjoomla php -i | grep max_
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
post_max_size => 101M => 101M
upload_max_filesize => 101M => 101M
ldap.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 150 => 150
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
pgsql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
```

There are any other settings to do? Did i miss anything?
thanks
carlo

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `custom.ini` file inside `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` with required parameters instead of putting it directly to `php.ini`

```
...
-v /data/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
...
```

Comment: maybe you don't read my run command line:
...
    -v /data/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini \
...
this is what i did.